# Confused with parameter definition of spectrometer

Tags: specifications, spectrum

Regarding [this](https://www.dlr.de/eoc/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-13622/23667_read-54280/) spectrometer specs, what is meant by "spectral sampling resolution"`? It is give as 2.55 nm. And how is that different from spectral resolution? The term "spectral sampling resolution" is confusing and wondering what it means in simpler terms.

Comment: What's the context? I'd imagine this would matter in Fourier-transform spectral interferometry, for example. But what's *your* context here?

Comment: That link does not list or use "spectral resolution" or "spectral sampling resolution" in a mutually exclusive fashion. It is possible to use slightly different terms, perhaps of varying specificity, to describe the same thing.